# $[0, ∞)$ onto the unit circle which is not a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Give an example of a continuous map of $[0, ∞)$ onto the unit circle which is
not a homeomorphism. $f(x)=e^{ix}$ works?

Comment: Yes, it does. And as it is not injective, it is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: Yes. Isn't that obvious? It takes a little more effort to make a map that is a bijection, though … but it can be done as well.

Comment: Restrict the map to the interval $[0,2\pi)$. Is that a homeomorphism?

Comment: It's a bijection, not a homeomorphism (no continuous inverse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that *any* map of $[0, ∞)$ onto the unit circle is not a homeomorphism, because the unit circle is compact and $[0, ∞)$ is not; in particular, $f(x)=e^{ix}$ works.